# On a sparsification trick controlling the asymptotics of a sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, probability-theory

EDIT: I must apologize I did not give the full hypothesis in order to answer this question, we also have that $X_1, \dots, X_n, \dots $ are iid random variables with $X_i \equiv X$ for all $i$, where $X$ is absolutely integrable.

I am following Terrence Tao notes on concentration inequalities that can be found [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/03/254a-notes-1-concentration-of-measure/#zero).

Define $S_n = X_1 + \dots + X_n$ where $X_i, 1 \le i \le n$ are random variables.

Tao states this sparsification Trick:

> Next, we apply a sparsification trick. Let ${0 < \epsilon < 1}.$ Suppose
>    that we knew that, almost surely, ${S_{n_m}/{n_m}}$ converged to ${{\bf
>  E} X}$ for ${n=n_m}$ of the form ${n_m := \lfloor (1+\epsilon)^m \rfloor}$
>    for some integer ${m}$. Then, for all other values of ${n}$, we see that
>    asymptotically, ${S_n/n}$ can only fluctuate by a multiplicative factor
>    of ${1+O(\epsilon)}$, thanks to the monotone nature of ${S_n}$. Because of
>    this and countable additivity, we see that it suffices to show that
>    ${S_{n_m}/{n_m}}$ converges to ${{\bf E} X}$. Actually, it will be enough
>    to show that almost surely, one has ${|S_{n_m}/{n_m} - {\bf E} X| \leq
>  \epsilon}$ for all but finitely many ${m}$.

Why can $S_n /n$ asymptotically only fluctuate by a multiplicative factor of $1 + O( \epsilon)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose for ease of presentation that in fact $S_{n_m}/n_m=EX$ for all $m$. Since $S_n$ is a monotone sequence (by a hypothesis a paragraph or three back), for any $n$ between $n_m$ and $n_{m+1}$, $S_n$ is now between $S_{n_m}=n_m EX$ and $S_{n_{m+1}}=n_{m+1} EX$ which differ by a factor of $1+\epsilon$.

Proving that result in general just requires you to handle $S_{n_m}/n_m-EX$ being small but nonzero and going through essentially the same argument. That is, take $m$ large enough for $\delta$-convergence, and then for any $n$ between $n_m$ and $n_{m+1}$ you have $n_m (EX-\delta) \leq S_n \leq n_{m+1}(EX+\delta)$.

Comment: Thank you! I think I have got it, one thing I remain dubious about what is meant by "$S_n /n$ asymptotically only fluctuate by a multiplicative factor of $1 + O( \epsilon)$". A multiplicative factor of $1 + O( \epsilon)$ can be arbitrary large...

Comment: @Monolite The point is that once you know that $S_{n_m}/n_m$ converges, you know that $S_n/n$ stays within a multiplicative factor of $1+O(\epsilon)$ of the "target". Sending $\epsilon \to 0$ (which changes $n_m$ of course) gives convergence.

Comment: Where would the proof not work if we were using $n$ instead of $n_m$?